# Ioncube Loader PHP 5.5 not installed

Tags: php, php-5.5, ioncube

I try to install Ioncube Loader with XAMPP and PHP 5.5.
I need this for XT Commerce on my local machine.
But I can't install it correctly.
After download from http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php
I unzip this folder to

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ioncube
```

After that I open the Test Page (`http://localhost/ioncube/loader-wizard.php?page=loader_check`)
and I get errors like:

```
The following problem has been found with the Loader installation:

    The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration file, C:\xampp\php\php.ini.
```

So I Add this Line to my php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\htdocs\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
```

I restart my Apache Server, and try again.
But now I didn't get errors ... but also a message that Iconcube isn't install correctly:

> ionCube Loader Wizard
>
> The ionCube Loader is not currently installed successfully.
>
> Please check that the Apache web server software has been restarted.

So what now? How can I install the ioncube Loader 5.5?

Comment: I get it. I use now the Installing with the Loader Installer from this page: https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php , and now it is running... :-O

Comment: Great to hear that it's working!

Comment: Loader is an .exe file.  How about solving this problem for a mac.  Got this error from using the wizard  so that is no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IonCube has a ready solution which leads you step by step. Just use wizard/installer from their page:

> Installing with the Loader Installer or Loader Wizard (recommended)
>
> It is recommended to install a Loader using the Loader Installer. The
>   Installer is a Windows application that can deploy a Loader
>   automatically to any supported operating system over FTP or SFTP. If
>   this cannot be used, we also provide a Loader Wizard PHP script that
>   gives guidance on installing manually.
>
> Loader Installer: ZIP
>
> Loader Wizard: ZIP TGZ
>
> To use the Wizard, 1) download and install the script into your web
>   space, then 2) launch the script in your browser. The Wizard will give
>   guidance on selection and installation of the correct Loader package.

Source and more info: http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

Answer (score 0):

verify if you version apache compilation is VC9 or VC11 and download correct package

You need add lines into php.ini and copy dlls from this paths:

```
zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"<br>
zend_extension_ts = "\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
```

and reset apache

Comment: Edited your post to fix typos and errors. zend_extension_ts was removed from PHP in PHP 5.3, and Zend Optimiser is irrelevant. Using the Loader Installer as the OP did with success is recommended, though doesn't hurt to learn what the underlying change is.